# Prompt continua não executando

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function numAleatorio(tamanho)
{
    var nums = '0123456789';
    var aleatorio = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length);
        aleatorio += letras.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }
    var palpite = numAleatorio(1)
    var x = prompt("Escreva um número de 0 a 9","0");
    var numero = parseInt(x);
    if (numero > 9){
        alert("Tá trapaceando né?")
    }
    if (numero == palpite){
        alert("o meu palpite é "+ palpite)
        alert("acertei? haha!")
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("aaah você ganhou...")
    }
}</script>
```

Comment: Como assim não executa ? Já agora o `prompt` lê uma string e não um numero

Comment: modifiquei o código, mas ele ainda não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das causas que possa estar impedindo a execução do código, já foi apontada pelo @Isac: o método `prompt` retorna uma string. Portanto, se você quer testar como um número, você pode usar a função `parseInt` para converter a string do prompt para inteiro, como o próprio nome diz.

A outra causa que possa também estar impedindo a execução do código, é que quando você foi comparar se há igualdade entre o `numero` e o `palpite`, você utilizou o operador de atribuição `=`, ao invés do operador de igualdade `==`.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: não está funcionando, ou, eu usei o parseInt errado.

Comment: Onde você está chamando essa função?

Comment: abaixo do prompt.

Comment: Eu digo a função `numAleatorio`

Comment: antes do prompt, atribuindo à variável palpite.

Comment: Mas, pelo código que está aí, a variável `palpite` está dentro da função

Comment: Agora eu entendi o erro, obrigado e perdoe-me pelo incômodo.

Comment: Sem problema! :)